# May I rely on the halachik leniency of others?

Tags: halacha, minhag, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, machlokes, leniencies

If "Reuven" believes the halacha to be one way and "Shimon" believes it to be more lenient may Reuven rely on Shimon to do something for him based on this leniency?

Here is a **100% fictional** practical example to illustrate the concept that I am asking about, please note I am **NOT** posing this as the actual question, the actual question is what was stated above: Reuven's Rav has given a psak that not using a kli **sheini** is bishul **m'deoraita**. Shimon's Rav holds you can use a kli rishon. Can Reuven drink a tea made for him by Shimon?

Comment: Might I suggest you remove the "or does he have a mitzvah to rebuke Shimon instead", which is a separate question?

Comment: 1. Even if you have to rebuke him you may be able to rely on it bdeieved (if someone carried a candy to your house on Shabbos through a true Reshus Harabim one could still eat it (defiantly after Shabbos Bichdei Sheyaaseh)).  2. One may not have to rebuke him but could still not rely on him Bedieved (for example, Sefardim can eat kitnios on Pesach lechatchila but an Ashkenazi can't eat a rice cake cooked by a Sefardi even Bdieved).

Comment: @msh210 good call. I was curious about the second part but it doesn't belong in this question, I have removed it.

Comment: Who holds that putting raw food in a kli rishon of hot liquid is NOT bishul d'oraisa???

Comment: @Will this is just a completely fabricated example

Comment: @Moshe it makes a real difference.  I might eat a dairy meal at in a religious family's home, without asking questions, even if they eat chalav stam, and I usually don't.  However, I would never eat in a home where they thought that milk from non-kosher animals is kosher!

Comment: are you asking qua maaseh shabbat or qua lifnei iver?

Comment: Moshe, if, as I suspect, you're asking a general question, "can I use the result of Shimon's actions if I believe them to be forbidden and he doesn't?", and don't care about the example, then perhaps leave the specific example out or specify clearly that you don't care about it, inasmuch as both Will and Double AA have, as you see, focused on details of the example.

Comment: I have amended the question. I opted to leave the example in because I think the question itself is abstract and I'm hoping an example will better illustrate the concepts. If someone would like to pose a better example I'm happy to replace.

Comment: @Moshe I think you misunderstood. The nature of the case is key as every case has it's own issues.

Comment: @msh210 I think you misunderstood my comment. No matter what the case, there are two perspectives one can approach from: the issue of causing a sin and the issue of benefiting from it. I used the shabbos terms, but those are the general questions for any case he brings. (Each case of course will have different ways of balancing the two...but see my previous comment for that.)

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10240

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From SimchasTorah's excellent answer to [Is it permissible to open soda cans on shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/155/is-it-permissible-to-open-soda-cans-on-shabbos)

> Even someone who does not open cans on Shabbos may use a can that was opened on Shabbos even if they were opened for him (Iggres Moshe: O"C Chelek Daled Siman Kuf Yud Tes Ois Heh) and does not require the person who opened it to drink from it. Non the less he may not ask someone to open it for him(Kuntres Yad Dodi, Harav Dovid Feinstein,pg. 31).

This is not necessarily an answer that applies all across the board, but at least it does indicate that such a principle exists.

Comment: I was once told that someone who doesn't hold of the eiruv may benefit from something that was carried by the person who does hold of the eiruv. No source, though.

Comment: @Menachem related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10240/ask-a-friend-to-carry-on-shabbos

Answer (score 1):

R. Gil Student [writes](http://www.torahmusings.com/2013/01/sin-for-me/):

> In summary, according to the Sha’ar Ha-Melekh, you may not assist someone to do something you consider forbidden even if he follows a different legitimate view. According to the Mabit, Kesav Sofer and R. Auerbach, you need not be concerned about lifnei iveir if someone follows a legitimate lenient view.
>
> ...
>
> From what we have discussed, it seems that during the week you are allowed to ask someone to do something that your rabbi considers forbidden but his rabbi considers permissible. R. Shlomo Zalman Auerbach and others rule that lifnei iveir does not apply and most authorities follow Rav Sama, that ein shali’ach li-dvar aveirah still applies. Halakhic pluralism means accepting that someone else may legitimately follow different religious practices than you.