# Asking someone to do melacha for you

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Is this permitted: There is a dispute if one can open bottles on Shabbas (just an example), there are *shittos* (opinions) who allow it, while others forbid it (don't want to get into that now). If I am one who believes it is *assur* (prohibited), and my friend believes that it is allowed, can I ask him to open up a bottle for me on Shabbas, or is this *assur* for me? If he does it himself it would seem *mutar*, but is he allowed to do this if I ask him to?

Comment: An answer here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14606 . Perhaps that question, though more general, is a duplicate. Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13513

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10240/759