# Can I help my friend who avoids the Internet on principle by booking airline tickets for him on the Internet?

Tags: internet, issur-vheter, chesed-kindness

I use the Internet (with safeguards).

My friend does not use the Internet because of the dangers.

Is it right for him to ask me to do jobs for him using the Internet (eg booking airline tickets)?

Is it right for me to help him by doing jobs for him using the Internet?

Do we say that since I am anyway using the Internet, I should certainly help my friend?

Or do we say that by  doing jobs for him using the Internet, I am encouraging him to see the advantages of being online and leading him astray?

Comment: By doing something for him, you are not encouraging him to see the advantages of being online and leading him astray, you are encouraging him to be able to continue not to have the internet as he does not need it.

Comment: Why do you say that using the internet in a responsible way is going astray?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14600/may-i-rely-on-the-halachik-leniency-of-others/14606#14606

Comment: @GershonGold Do you think like me that the principle of the question is answered in your reference? If so, let's close it.

Comment: I think it may. Not sure. Perhaps let others weigh in.

Comment: I read an article by a nonjewish college professor who tried an experiment to see if he could go internet free for a certain amount of time. When he was desperate, he had a colleague go on the internet for him. He justified this by saying his colleague was his Shabbos Goy! His terminology, not mine. Oy what chillul Hashem. Too bad it's so funny.

Comment: @Daniel I meant that I might lead him astray according to **his** understanding - not mine.

Comment: As I wrote [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53720/440) most authorities summarized by R. Gil Student would seem to permit. However, I could see a potential distinction here, as he may not be allowed to ask you according to his posek (as the posek may have the problem of someone being drawn to the internet that they may not have about heter mechira food, for example). Not sure how much that would or would not be your responsibility.

Comment: @user6591 Not necessarily a chillul Hashem if the professor really understands what that means.

Comment: This really does seem to be a dupe, even though the question over there gave a somewhat unfortunate example that could include other factors.

Comment: Also, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10240