# Can one use an Eruv if the Rabbi who built it says its down?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, halacha-theory

If a Rav Hamachsheir of an Eruv, the Rabbi who built it and supervises its use, sends out a message that he holds that the Eruv is down because of a particular reason (reason X), and should not be used. However, let's say a person who lives in the area of the Eruv asks his Posek, Halachik decider, who notifies him that he holds reason X is not a really a problem and any Eruv with that "issue" is still permissible to be carried in according to him.

Are there any sources one can bring that although one's own Posek thinks there is no issue with the Eruv in question, if the Rav Hamachsheir holds that there is an issue that you still should not use it? If so, would there be a difference between carrying something small in your pocket, so not to be going publicly against the decision of the Rav Hamachsheir, as opposed to something larger that can be seen?

Sources to support a theory would be appreciated.

Comment: Very few people IME ask about what Kulas and/or Chumras a given city Eruv has before relying on it. If someone doesn't usually ask about this sort of thing relying on the Rav HaMachshir, then it seems rather hypocritical to suddenly have an opinion on the matter when a Kula is at stake.

Comment: I wouldn't without further clarification, as the Rov won't tell you if anything else goes wrong (The wire ripped)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin That's not always the case. Seemingly, a good rav hamachshir who knows it's machloket will fix everything else so those who will carry anyway have at least some opinions to rely on instead of being vadai be'issur. The OP's case is seemingly where they have the 'inside scoop' of what's going on, eg. one of the Eruv Checkers.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10240/759

Comment: If your posek says X, and you don't follow that, is he still your posek?